# Configure DNS on sub-domain for testing web site on dynamic IP

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, subdomain, dynamic-dns

I am running a web site on a dedicate server at IP 12.34.56.78.  The DNS is configured like so:

```
*       A          12.34.56.78  
@       A          12.34.56.78
@       MX     10  mail.mydomain.co.uk
ftpes   CNAME      mydomain.co.uk.  
staff   A          12.34.56.78
www     CNAME      mydomain.co.uk.
mail    CNAME      mydomain.co.uk.
```

However, I need have a temporary duplicate of this site (hosted on a different IP) for testing purposes, but accessible via a subdomain.  Normally to achieve this I would add this record:

```
test    CNAME      98.76.54.32
```

However, in this case the duplicate site is hosted on an Azure VM, and is not permanently live.  Therefore, the IP changes each time the VM is brought online.

I've been looking at dynamic DNS services, but can't find enough information to answer the question, which is, is it possible to point a subdomain at a dynamic service which then handles the **real** (changing IP) automatically.  Perhaps something like this...

```
test    CNAME      dynamicIpProvider.org
```

I'd prefer not to have to migrate *all* the DNS settings to the dynamic provider if possible, and also not to have to set up a new domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Dynamics DNS providers usually let you set IP of machine to one of the subdomains they offer. You can then configure of your subdomain records as a CNAME of said domain.

So lets say you get `mysite.no-ip.com` to use for Dynamic DNS. You then configure `test` subdomain on your main domain as a CNAME to `mysite.no-ip.com`.

Comment: Perfect.  That's exactly what I'd hoped for.  Thank you very much (your edit was perfect!)